# Can $(a+b+c+d+e)^4 - (a^4 + b^4 + c^4 + d^4 + e^4 + 1)$, for natural $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$, be a perfect square?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose there are five natural numbers $a,b,c,d,e.$ Prove that the expression $$(a+b+c+d+e)^4 - (a^4 + b^4 + c^4 + d^4 + e^4 + 1)$$ can never be a perfect square.

I have tried factorizing, as well as expanding and using bounding conditions, however I have not been able to find a solution.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I'd guess that the subtraction by one is the key

Answer (score 1):

Let's work modulo $8$. One can notice that if $n^{4}$ is a forth power of a natural number then $n^4$ is congruent to either $0$ or $1$ modulo $8$.

Let's suppose that $(a+b+c+d+e)^{4}\equiv 1 \mod 8$. Then $a^{4}+b^{4}+c^{4}+d^{4}+e^{4}$ must be congruent to $4$ (if we suppose that the given expression is a perfect square then there are only three options modulo $8$). Indeed, it cannot be congruent to $-1$ (in order to get $1$ modulo $8$) and if it is congruent to $0$, then $a,b,c,d,e$ are all even numbers, so $(a+b+c+d+e)^{4}\equiv 1 \mod 8$ cannot hold. In order for $a^{4}+b^{4}+c^{4}+d^{4}+e^{4}$ to be congruent to $4$ all numbers but one must be congruent to $1$. So we get four odd numbers and one even (among $a,b,c,d,e$). But again we conclude that $(a+b+c+d+e)^{4}\equiv 0\mod 8$, contradiction.

Now suppose that $(a+b+c+d+e)^{4}\equiv 0 \mod 8$. It means that $a+b+c+d+e$ is even. Then $a^{4}+b^{4}+c^{4}+d^{4}+e^{4} + 1$ must be congruent to either $0,-1$ or $4$. The first two are clearly impossible. In order to get $4$ all but $2$ numbers (among $a^{4},\ldots,e^{4}$) must be congruent to $1$. So we get three odd numbers and two even among $a,b,c,d,e$, which means that $a+b+c+d+e$ is odd and $(a+b+c+d+e)^{4}\equiv 0 \mod 8$ cannot hold.

I think that there is a mistake somewhere, but I'll still post this...

Comment: Solution is correct, though the presentation could be greatly improved. A slightly easier approach (which is essentially your ideas) would be to consider cases based on how many of $a, b, c, d, e$ are odd, and showing that the expression is $ \equiv 3, 5, 7 \pmod{8}$ hence cannot be a perfect square.